# Mysql Error when trying to spit out database elements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I keep getting this error :

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dbViewer.php on line 71
```

Could not get data:

from this code

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('Version') AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'wp_plugin_db'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
}

 $arrayCount = 0;


 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
 {

  $tableNames[$arrayCount] = $row[0];
  $arrayCount++;
 }

 foreach ($tableNames as $siteName) {
    $siteName =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$siteName);
    $sql="SELECT Plugin_Name, Version, WPVersion FROM `".$siteName."` ORDER BY   Plugin_Name";

    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if(! $result )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "Website Name:  $siteName ----  " ;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "  Plugin Name :{$row['Plugin_Name']}   ".
             "  Version : {$row['Version']}  ". 
             "  Wordpress Version : {$row['WPVersion']}  ".
             "   |    ";


    } 
    echo "<br>";
 }

mysqli_close($con);
```

The error says `line 71` which is `die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error());`

The real error is happening at `$sql="SELECT Plugin_Name, WPVersion, Version FROM ".$siteName." ORDER BY Plugin_Name";`

I know this because when I take out WPVersion from the selec and comment out the echo for that element it works without error. Please help I can't seem to figure this out, Is it syntax? I feel so stupid haha.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you actually READ the error? You forgot to pass in the link paramter to mysqli, e.g.

```
mysqli_error($con);
             ^^^^--- missing
```

Comment: If thats the case then why does it work when I comment out what I had said>

Comment: AND where do I need to add that? $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql); already has the connection or "link"

Comment: You're using it procedurally, not as an object. Therefore the function needs the link passed to it. Needs to be `die('Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($con));`. You use it twice, it's the second query that's failing, thus throwing the die message.

Comment: Some of the mysqli functions accept statement handles, which have the connection handle information embedded in them> That's why you only have to do `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` instead of `mysqli_fetch_assoc($con, $result)`. mysqli_error REQUIRES a connection handle, which is exactly what your error message says.

Comment: Hey thx guys, I get it now and although that didn't fix my error it allowed the debugger to give me more information. That actual error was I was selecting a column that wasn't in one of my other tables which was causing my error.